# Firebase: Flutter: Avoiding Transaction crashes CloudFirestorePlugin.java:613 : .then() vs async/await

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous

My app has recently been crashing relentlessly due to Transactions and listeners. I want to make sure I am using Transactions correctly before I lead a crusade to have these systems fixed.

```
INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: A transaction object cannot be used after its update callback has been invoked.
io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$5.doInBackground
```

Logically this error leads me to believe that somehow, within a single transaction, either immediately or during a retry, some key identifying the transaction is mishandled. I came across an interesting post with 'claimed solution' being to switch from async/await to .then() calls after the transaction.get(doc).

This makes some sense, forcing the write to happen only after the get is completed. However, it was someone here on StackOverflow that recommended I should use async/await in transactions instead of the .then() I initially used everywhere.

Another thing I want to make sure I'm doing correctly is returning the correct Future related to the Transaction. I've seen countless examples with different returns, some without return at all.

What IS the right way to use transactions for stability?

1) My current method EXAMPLE:

```
List<String> _activeTransactionUpdate = [];

Future transactionUpdateSet(
    {@required DocumentReference docRef, @required Map<String, dynamic> payload, bool forceSet = false})
{
  if (_activeTransactionUpdate.contains(docRef.path)) {
    printRed('**********TRANSATION UPDATE DUPLICATE**********\n${docRef.path}');
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
  }
  return Firestore.instance.runTransaction((t) async {
    var doc = await t.get(docRef);
    return doc.exists
        ? t.update(docRef, payload)
        : forceSet ? t.set(docRef, payload) : t.update(docRef, {});
  }).then((_) => _activeTransactionUpdate.remove(docRef.path));
}
```

2) Proposed method EXAMPLE

```
List<String> _activeTransactionUpdate = [];

Future transactionUpdateSet(
    {@required DocumentReference docRef, @required Map<String, dynamic> payload, bool forceSet = false})
{
  if (_activeTransactionUpdate.contains(docRef.path)) {
    printRed('**********TRANSATION UPDATE DUPLICATE**********\n${docRef.path}');
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
  }
  return Firestore.instance.runTransaction((t) {
    return t.get(docRef).then((doc) {
      return doc.exists
        ? t.update(docRef, payload)
        : forceSet ? t.set(docRef, payload) : t.update(docRef, {});
    });
  }).then((_) => _activeTransactionUpdate.remove(docRef.path));
}
```

FYI, I used the transaction map key checker to make sure one client wasn't trying to update a given document more than once at the same time.

EDIT: QQ https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1969

Answer (score 0):

It appears that transactions from Flutter to Firebase have some serious issues : https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1969 

Looking through similar threads, these issues appear to have persisted for over six months now. I was surprised to learn that although both Firebase and Flutter are Google products, the communication between them is not a Google product.

At this time, if you have a highly database active app depending on many transactions you will likely experience these crashes. Many of the core mechanisms meant to protect transactions are what seem to be causing them to fail.

I am deciding how to move forward, but looks like I will have to use a mixed bag of solutions and remove most, possibly all of my runTransaction calls.

Transactions can likely fail fatally if:

1. A transaction needs to retry.
2. Two parallel transactions occur from multiple clients.
3. Two transactions to different locations from one client are in close succession.
4. doing the same transaction from one client in close succession to it's previous call.

Even if you're a saint with your async/await or .then() calls, these problems persist.

PLEASE... PLEASE someone correctly me if I'm wrong.